# Calling Init method using Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, atl

How to call `Init(_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* p, HINSTANCE h, UINT nServiceNameID)` with recent compilers  ?

```
CServiceModule _Module;
OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(TestObj), CTestObj)
//...
inline void CServiceModule::Init(_ATL_OBJMAP_ENTRY* p, HINSTANCE h, UINT nServiceNameID)
{
    CComModule::Init(p, h);

    m_bService = TRUE;

    LoadString(h, nServiceNameID, m_szServiceName, sizeof(m_szServiceName) / sizeof(TCHAR));

    // set up the initial service status
    m_hServiceStatus = NULL;
    m_status.dwServiceType = SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS;
    m_status.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_STOPPED;
    m_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP;
    m_status.dwWin32ExitCode = 0;
    m_status.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0;
    m_status.dwCheckPoint = 0;
    m_status.dwWaitHint = 0;
}
```

I've tried to use `_Module.Init(CTestObj, hInstance, IDS_SERVICENAME);`, but this wouldn't work. I'm getting an error an `CTestObj` saying that CTestObj is undefined. And when I add `OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO(__uuidof(BeeperObj), CBeeperObj)`, I got the following error `C2065: 'CreateInstance' : undeclared identifier`.

PS: I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Any brilliant idea, please?

Comment: Please show the scope / code you're trying to call it from. CTestObj undefined indicated you're trying to pass an object that you haven't yet defined, nothing wrong with the function you're calling itself.

Comment: @OMGtechy, Haven't I mentionned it? **_Module.Init(CTestObj, hInstance, IDS_SERVICENAME);** CTestObj already exists, but I'm getting that error, when I try to call it.

Comment: You need to show the code around it to, as that has a big affect on this. For example, I need to check that you've defined _Module and CTestObject, so all the code in the same scope would be helpful.

Comment: You still need to add more code, as I can't see what the macro involving CTestObj does

Comment: Just pass `NULL` for the first parameter of `Init`. Entries introduced by `OBJECT_ENTRY_AUTO` are picked up automatically, and don't need to be explicitly passed in (hence `AUTO`).

Comment: Re: `'CreateInstance' : undeclared identifier`. I bet `CBeeperObj` is not derived from `CComCoClass`